# How to select a text node on jquery without selecting the sibiling

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML that is structured like this:

```
<div class="ProductPriceRating">
    <em>
        <strike class="RetailPriceValue">$65.00</strike> 
        $45.00
    </em>
</div>
```

I need to select the "$45.00". I thought this would work:

```
$('.ProductPriceRating strike').siblings().css('background','red');
```

But it didn't

Comment: I'm targeting the $45.00, not the $65.00

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot apply a style to a text node, you need to wrap it with an element

Try

```
var node = $('.ProductPriceRating strike').get(0).nextSibling;
$(node).wrap('<span/>').parent().css('background','red');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mWfT8/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't style text nodes directly, instead wrap it in a span and style that:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ProductPriceRating">
    <em>
        <strike class="RetailPriceValue">$65.00</strike> 
        <span>$45.00</span>
    </em>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.ProductPriceRating strike').siblings().css('background','red');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cWJJv/)**

If you can't change the HTML structure, you can try styling the `em` and the `strike`:

```
$('.ProductPriceRating em').css('background','red');
$('.ProductPriceRating strike').css('background','white');
```